# How to create extension method taking lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, extension-methods

Greetings,

I'm looking for a way to convert

```
foreach (var sEvent in Events)
{
    sEvent.SomeId = 0;
}
```

to

```
Events.Set(m=>m.SomeId, 0);
```

or something like this.

So basicly I want to make it a one line event that sets all "SomeId" to 0;

Is there any way?

Comment: There's no "Lambda Extension", you have merged 2 concepts in one: "Lambda expression" and "Extension Methods".

Comment: True but I was looking for a way to implement lambda in a extension. But it seems there already is a method that does what I want.

Comment: mine was just a clarification. To be more precise the title should have been "How to create extension method taking lambda expression". Your purpose was clear though :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `Events` is a `List<T>` you can use:

```
Events.ForEach( m => m.SomeId = 0 );
```

If `Events` is `IEnumerable`, `ForEach` is not implemented, but you can of course make your own ForEach that works on `IEnumerable` yourself. The reason `ForEach` is not created for `IEnumerable`, is that [they did not want to have extension method on `IEnumerable` with side effects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) (that altered the original collection).

Implementing ForEach on IEnumerable is easy enough:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
  foreach (T element in source) 
    action(element);
  return source;
}
```

This has to go into a `static` class just like all other extension methods.

Comment: @Kirk Woll - A reference to Eric Lippert's blog is very often a good idea :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
Events.ToList().ForEach(Event => Event.SomeId = 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

If `Events` is a `List<T>` you can simply use

```
Events.ForEach(e => e.SomeId = 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

If Events is a List, you could do:

```
Events.ForEach(m => m.SomeId = 0);
```